# Swagger 2.0 for Spring MVC not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, swagger-2.0

I have some REST APIs written using Spring MVC. I am trying to implement Swagger2.0 into this. I am not using Spring Boot and I am also not using the swagger-ui dependency. My aim is to generate the docs of my APIs in JSON format.

I referenced the following links:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/tree/master/spring-java-swagger
and
[A 'simple' way to implement Swagger in a Spring MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720090/a-simple-way-to-implement-swagger-in-a-spring-mvc-application)

However, I am unable to see the docs when I visit http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs. I believe I am missing something really simple, especially with my Spring configuration file.

I have the following dependency in my **pom.xml** file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**SwaggerConfig.java**

```
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
/* import statements */

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sample.controller"})
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    public WebConfig(){
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket documentation() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

}
```

**Spring configuration XML** contains the following:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Any help would be appreciated. Again, I am not planning on using Spring Boot and I would be configuring swagger-ui once I get this working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please refer link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607046/controller-does-not-appear-in-swagger-ui-html/39631927#39631927

Comment: Thank you for the response @Vaibs. I will come back to this thread in case I cannot get it to work.

Comment: If you are using Spring Security, use the security configuration mentioned on **[Cannot open Swagger UI in tis Version 3 in my Spring Boot Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73073519/cannot-open-swagger-ui-in-tis-version-3-in-my-spring-boot-example)** page.